# Positioning cross browsers

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have:

```
#nameDiv
{
    height: 0px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -22px;
    left: 134px;
}

#nameDivDuplicate
{
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -22px;
    left: 134px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

And in my view I have:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Name:</b> </td><td><input type="text" id="txtName" maxlength="100"/>
    <div id="nameDiv"  title="The Name is required.">
        <img title="The Name is required." src="error.jpg" id="txtNameRequired"/>
    </div>
    <div id="nameDivDuplicate"  title="The address already exists.">
        <img title="The address already exists." src="error.jpg" id="txtNameDuplicate"/>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>Address: </td><td><input type="text" id="txtAddress"  maxlength="100"/> </td>
</tr>
```

The nameDiv and the nameDivDuplicate divs have sidplay:none at first. Then, with jquery I show them. I need them to be shown in the same place as txtName (on its right).

The code above is good for Google Chrome, but not for the other browsers. How is this handled?

Comment: FYI there's no such thing as a `title` attribute on `img` element. Or as well as on quite any other HTML element (div, table, whatever), not in the way you intended to add it. What you meant was an `alt` attribute (mandatory on img), maybe your confusion comes from old IEs that, if I remember well, for a long time displayed alt as a tooltip and displayed title if img was missing, the exact contrary of what should be done. EDIT What is OK is a title attribute on links when their text isn't sufficient by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be really careful with position:relative.  It can really give you some headaches.  There have been a lot of issues (in IE in particular) with position:relative.

I would recommend not using it in this case.  Rather, I would place extra td tags around your two error images to have them create their own column.  This will place them to the right of txtName's input box.

```
<tr>
<td><b>Name:</b> </td>
<td><input type="text" id="txtName" maxlength="100"/></td>
<td>
    <div id="nameDiv"  title="The Name is required.">
       <img title="The Name is required." src="error.jpg" id="txtNameRequired"/>
    </div>
    <div id="nameDivDuplicate"  title="The address already exists.">
       <img title="The address already exists." src="error.jpg" id="txtNameDuplicate"/>
    </div>
</td>
<td>Address: </td><td><input type="text" id="txtAddress"  maxlength="100"/> </td>
</tr>
```

EDIT:
Since you said you didn't want a new column, you could add a div tag around everything inside that td tag, and use float:left to have them all line up, or you could set the width.

```
#nameDiv { width: 20px; float:left; }
#nameDivDuplicate { float:left; }
#txtName { float:left; }
```

I bolded the new DIV that I added.

```
<td><b>Name:</b> </td>
<td>
  **<div>**<input type="text" id="txtName" maxlength="100"/>
    <div id="nameDiv"  title="The Name is required.">
        <img title="The Name is required." src="error.jpg" id="txtNameRequired"/>
    </div>
    <div id="nameDivDuplicate"  title="The address already exists.">
        <img title="The address already exists." src="error.jpg" 
             id="txtNameDuplicate"/>
    </div>
  **</div>**
</td>
<td>Address: </td>
<td><input type="text" id="txtAddress"  maxlength="100"/> </td>
```

Comment: I can't do that - I have another column and it will be moved because of this.

Comment: how about wrapping all 3 elements (the input box and the 2 divs with images) with another DIV tag, and adding float:left to each of the 3?  Edited answer above to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

`position:relative` is supposed to be used in conjunction with `position:absolute`, where `position:relative` in a parent element is setting the origin point of the absolutely-positioned child element.

You are not using it this way.